# Need help with LyX

Tags: lyx

I have two problems:

(a) I can't seem to get LyX to convert LaTeX to pdf. I've changed the path in Tools>Preferences>Paths>PATH prefix to where Acrobat is installed but it does not work.

(b) All the text I type is 'bunched up', like this:
[image]

Any help with these will be much appreciated. I am on LyX 1.6.7

Comment: Hi and welcome! I have never seen this in LyX. I would highly recommend upgrading your LyX version to 2.1.2. Your version is more than 4 years old.

Comment: Also, in the future please give a more informative title.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You seem to be asking two unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions. (a): You still need a TeX distribution. (b): That is *really* weird. Upgrade :)

Comment: Acrobat is simply the document viewing program. It has nothing to do with creating the PDF. Can you compile a basic latex document from the command line using pdflatex? (For example one of the package source docs.) Can you then import this same document into LyX and compile that? It would also help to know what platform you're on and what your TeX distribution is.

Answer (score 2):

(a) Here, the path to the `*latex` binaries is asked (e.g. `pdflatex`, `tex` etc.). Btw, you can use LyX even without having a pdf-viewer. You can export to various formats.

(b) As others said in the comments, please upgrade your LyX version. The new ones are even easier to install.